# Get value from input to the insert

Tags: php

Hello i need to send from input type submit the same values like in this example ;

```
echo '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="wystaw.php?skinName='. $key['weapon']. " "  .$key['skin'] .'">Wystaw</a></td>';
```

i need it to insert in database skins which the user need to sold. And i must use input no anchor tag.

[PHOTO OF PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA20D.png)

Comment: please specify what you want ? do you want to save the weapon and skin value in database?

Comment: Yes. And i need to do it in one file.

Comment: If you want to send additional parameters by submitting a form instead of clicking a link, then put those into the form as hidden fields.